# Docker CPU/Mem allocation in Mac/Win

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine, docker-for-windows, docker-for-mac

As far as I understood, at the moment, Docker for Mac requires that I decide **upfront** how much memory and CPU cores to statically allocate to the virtualized linux it runs on.

[image]

So that means that **even when Docker is idle**, my other programs will run on (N-3) CPU cores and (M-3)GB of memory. Right?

This is very suboptimal!

In Linux, it's ideal because a container is just another process. So it uses and releases the system memory as containers starts and stop.

1. Is my mental model correct?
2. Will one day Docker for Mac or Windows **dynamically allocate** CPU and Memory resources?

Answer (score 4):

The primary issue here is that, for the moment, Docker can only run Linux containers *on Linux*.  That means on OS X or Windows, Docker is running in a Linux VM, and it's ability to allocate resources is limited by the facilities provided by the virtualization software in use.

Of course, Docker can natively on Windows, as long as you want to run Windows containers, and in this situation may more closely match the Linux "a container is just a process" model.

It is *possible* that this will change in the future, but that's how things stand right now.

> So that means that even when Docker is idle, my other programs will run on (N-3) CPU cores and (M-3)GB of memory. Right?

I suspect that's true for memory.  I believe that if the docker vm is idle it isn't actually using much in the way of CPU resources (that is, you are not dedicating CPUs to the VM; rather, you are setting maximum limits on how many resources the vm can consume).

Comment: this is the strongest argument to me for buying a Linux laptop 